# GWT: Where (how) to define POJOs to make em available for client and server? (and to use datastore on serverside)

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt, persistence, google-cloud-datastore, gwt-rpc

I try to get an application running which should interact with a server via RPC (JDO in Google DataStore). So I defined a persistent POJO on the server-side to get it put in the datastore via the PersistenceManager (as shown in the gwt rpc tuts). Everything works fine. But I am not able to receive the callback POJO on the client side because the POJO is only defined on server-side. How can I realize it, that the client knows that kind of object??
(sry for my bad english)
Lars

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put your POJOs in a separate package/directory (e.g. com.example.common) and then add source declaration to your GWT module descriptor (xyz.gwt.xml):

```
<source path="common"/> //relative to your xyz.gwt.xml location
```

GWT compiler will then also compile POJOs and they will be seen by your other GWT code.

Edited:
@Lars - now I understand your problem. As I see it you have several options:

1. If possible use Objectify instead of JDO. Objectify uses pure POJOs and they play nicely with GWT. I use this in my projects. One nice thing that Objectify gives you is @PostLoad & @ PrePersist on methods to run some code before/after POJOs are loaded/saved to datastore. I use this to handle serialization of GeoPoint for instance.
2. Use JDO and make copies of your domain classes. This is a pain but it would work. Use 'transient' java keyword in your server JDO classes to exclude fields you do not want to RPC.

Edit #2: There is a third option that you might prefer:

1. Create "fake" JDO annotation classes using super-sourcing. This is a common technique to replace classes with a GWT version. Described here: http://fredsa.allen-sauer.com/2009/04/1st-look-at-app-engine-using-jdo.html

Comment: Thats what I first thought about too, but the problem is that you have to declare a class as capable of being stored and retrieved from the datastore with JDO, giving the class a @PersistenceCapable annotation. And if you do so, this class in not compilable for the client side.

Comment: Updated a post with an example how to use JDO and HWT together using "fake" classes.

Comment: Objectify is the way to go! Thx (to Xo4yHaMope too)

Answer (score 0):

You can use DTO([stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051182/what-is-data-transfer-object), [moar](http://java.sun.com/blueprints/corej2eepatterns/Patterns/TransferObject.html)) for transferring data to client.
Basic sample [here](http://code.google.com/p/google-app-engine-samples/source/browse/trunk/gwtguestbook-namespaces/src/com/google/gwt/sample/gwtguestbook/server/GuestServiceImpl.java) (method `getTenLatestEntries()` in your case).
Or you can use some third-party libraries like [objectify](http://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/wiki/ObjectifyWithGWT) and stop worry about making DTO`s.