# Models as pure data objects in Zend Framework and the service layer

Tags: php, model-view-controller, oop, zend-framework, service-layer

It has become common to treat models in ZF as pure data objects, i.e. a class instance with a bunch of attributes and getters/setters.

```
class Model_User {
  public $id;
  public $name;
  ...
}
```

What I'm wondering is whether or not it makes sense to, for example, instantiate such an object in a controller and pass it *to* a service layer, or whether or not the service layer should itself be responsible for instantiating these objects... You would not instantiate a `Zend_DbTable` class directly in the controller, so does it make much sense to instantiate a `Model_User` in a controller to pass it to a service?

Comment: My reason for asking this is that I often find myself passing arrays from a controller to a service layer only to then pass them straight to a model...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see a problem with doing it this way. Data Transport Objects (DTO) are meant to pass information between layers and/or modules. In my opinion this is no different that using arrays and it certainly is easier than using arrays.

Here is another discussion over DTOs - [What is Data Transfer Object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051182/what-is-data-transfer-object)

And Martin's definition on DTOs - http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataTransferObject.html