# How to add to an arraylist of class type

Tags: java, arraylist

Ok so this is what I have

```
public class Register {

    public String propertyID;
    public String PPSNumber;

    Register(String aPropertyID, String aPPSNumber) {
        propertyID = aPropertyID;
        PPSNumber = aPPSNumber;
    }

    public void setPPSNumber(String aPPSNumber) {
        PPSNumber = aPPSNumber;
    }

    public String getPPSNumber() {
        return PPSNumber;
    }

    public String getPropertyID() {
        return propertyID;
    }
}
```

Then I have this

```
public static ArrayList<Register> registers = new ArrayList<Register>();

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String userInput1 = "", userInput2 = "", userInput3 = "";
    userInput1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your PPSNumber");
    userInput2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your propID");

    registers.add("number", "id");
}
```

I don't understand why It wont let me add to the ArrayList. Is there some way of adding class types to ArrayLists?

Comment: How does one print out the arraylist registers. Also how do you add multiple registers eg. multiple ppsnumbers and ids?

Answer (score 4):

Try this instead :

```
registers.add(new Register("number","id"));
```

EDIT 1:
To answer your question, you can create a separate "register" and the use the getters :

```
Register aRegister = new Register("number","id");
registers.add(aRegister);
System.out.println(aRegister.getPropertyID()+" "+ aRegister.getPPSNumber());
```

Comment: How do you print whats inside of register then?

Comment: Thanks for the help one more question.
Classes are new to me hence all the questions.
I will be reading in alot of IDs and PPSNumbers into the registers arraylist. But I dont want to have to creat a new register (aRegister) for each id/property, that wouldnt work. How do I do that. Thanks again.

Comment: @user2079139: Why wouldn't it work? It would work without any problem. Do that.

Answer (score 0):

Your `List` is of type `Register` so you need to add object of `Register` class only.

Nothing wrong in create as many Register objects as required.

You can implement `toString()` method inside `Register` class then the below sysout will work given the `register` variable is initialized with `Register` object. Check this [How to override toString() properly in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10734106/how-to-override-tostring-properly-in-java) to know about toString implementation.

```
System.out.println(register)
```