# Convert object to string ( java )

Tags: java

I have a question how to convert an object item to string , 
in the source code here you can see that you can input  Object item as an object  , however I would want the  item  to be converted into a  string  so I can equal it to a string variable .
Does anybody know how to do this ?

Thank you

---

```
public QueueNode AddItem (Object item, int priority) 
{


    PQNode newNode = new PQNode (item, priority);
    if (root != null) {

        spreadingOutToInsert (newNode);

        // if newNode equals or is greater than the root then  put the old root as the rightChild of the newnode

        if (newNode.compare (root) < 0) 

        {
            newNode.leftNode  = root.leftNode;

            newNode.right = root;

            root.leftNode     = null;

            // if newNode equals or is greater than the root then just put the old root as the leftChild of the newnode
        } else 
        {
            newNode.leftNode  = root;

            newNode.right = root.right;

            root.right    = null;
        }; 

    }; 

    size++;
    return root = newNode;    // this is to make the newNode into the new root

};
```

Comment: Can't you simply write a method? Either manually or [override toString()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10734106/how-to-override-tostring-properly-in-java).

Answer (score 2):

You use `(String)item` if you want to explicitly cast the type, but be careful. Ideally you should override the `toString()` for the class and call that instead to return a `String`.

Comment: Say what?  `(String)item` does not _convert_ anything.  All it does is tell the compiler, "trust me, I know that the `item` variable holds a reference to a `String`."  But what if it _doesn't_ hold a reference to a String?  You get a runtime error, which probably is not what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compare the output of the default toString() implementation inherited from Object, it will look something like this: Ex@7852e922

You could always implement a toString() method to override the default behavior. Also, instead of (String) item you could call item.toString(). Read the toString() and hashcode() methods in:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html

As stated before, the classname@hashcode representation might be enough to do what you need to do.