# How to write the contents of my array in a text file?

Tags: java, arrays

I have an array which has objects of people in a football team. It holds information such as their first name, second name and address. When i use the code shown below the text file contains values like this: member@29086037

The code is shown below:

```
try
{
    PrintWriter pr = new PrintWriter ("memberDetails.txt");
    for (int i = 0; i < collection.length; i++)
    {
    pr.println(collection[i]); 
    }
    pr.close();
} catch (FileNotFoundException ex)
{
    System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    System.out.println("in" + System.getProperty("user.dir"));
    System.exit(1);
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what Object type is your array ? show us how you are declaring your array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `pr.println(collection[i]);` as you didn't override it, you print [Object::toString](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString()) which represents the object in this way by default:

> The toString method for class Object returns a string consisting of the name of the class of which the object is an instance, the at-sign character `@', and the unsigned hexadecimal representation of the hash code of the object. In other words, this method returns a string equal to the value of:

```
 getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())
```

To print each field, use properties of the object, for example:

```
collection[i].getName(); 
collection[i].getAddress();
```

Other option, is to [override toString()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10734106/how-to-override-tostring-properly-in-java) method of `member`.

Comment: *When you do pr.println(collection[i]); you print the object reference* this is not what happens. Instead, it calls `collection[i].toString()`. From the output, seems like the class doesn't override this method, so this boils down to execute `super.toString()` which ends in `Object#toString`.

Comment: I always thought by default toString prints the internal reference in java, fixed,... Thanks! ;)

Comment: if my array is not full and i try to write to a file i get a null pointer exception. How could i fix this?

Comment: 1) create the array with exact size or 2) check if `collections[i] == null` before reading the line, or 3) better, use a premade `Collection` such as [ArrayList](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com.es/2011/05/example-of-arraylist-in-java-tutorial.html) which will manage the sizes for you.

Answer (score 3):

When you see that malarky with the numbers and class name like that, it means you haven't overriden your `toString()` method, so it defaults to `Object.toString()`.

So, override the `public String toString()` method on your `member` class.

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide the path to the file correctly. I would suggest creating a file object and then pass it to Printwriter. This way you can also make sure if File exist before assigning it to printwriter.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, assuming you have a class that models the players, you should provide a `toString()` implementation in the class. For example:

```
public class Player {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String address;
    ...
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("Name: %s, %s. Address: %s", lastName, firstName, address);
    }
}
```

After that's been done, it becomes trivial to write the player information into a file. Using an utility library such as Google's [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/GuavaExplained), the solution simplifies into a one-liner:

```
Files.write(Joiner.on(StandardSystemProperty.LINE_SEPARATOR.value())
                  .join(collection),
            new File("memberDetails.txt"),
            Charsets.UTF_8);
```