# How to Create a java program of computing student grades

Tags: java, algorithm, oop

I was asked to create a java OOP program with the following specifications:

> Student Grade                  Name : String                 Id :
>   String                   math grade : double           english grade :
>   double         science grade : double                   Average () :
>   double                            printInfo () : void

The Instructions are:

> 1)Create Student Grade Class
>
> 2)Create an Array of 10 Student
>
> 3) Enter Grade info using Keyboard
>
> 4) Print list of students (name and average)

My problem is every time I run the public class `StudentGradeApp2` it always gives me this error

> ```
>  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
>   at javaDay3.StudentGradeApp2.main(StudentGradeApp2.java:15)
> ```

Now i do not know what to put on this portion:

```
public static void printTheStudentDetails (StudentGrade info) {
```

please oh please help me

My codes are: 
`StudentGrade` Class:

```
    package javaDay3;

    public class StudentGrade {

            String name;
            String id;
            double mathgrade;
            double enggrade;
            double scigrade;

            public void printInfo() {
                System.out.println("Math = " + mathgrade);
                System.out.println("English = " + enggrade);
                System.out.println("Science = " + scigrade);
                System.out.println( "Average = " + average());
        }
        public double average () {
            return ((mathgrade + enggrade + scigrade) / 3);
    }
        public void printCompleteInformation() {
            System.out.println("Name = " + name);
            System.out.println("ID = " + id);
            System.out.println("Math = " + mathgrade);
            System.out.println("English = " + enggrade);
            System.out.println("Science = " + scigrade);
            System.out.println( "Average = " + average());
        }
        public void printNeed () {
            System.out.println("Name = " + name);
            System.out.println( "Average = " + average());
        }   
    }
```

StudentGradeApp Class:

```
    package javaDay3;

    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class StudentGradeApp {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            StudentGrade stud1 = new StudentGrade ();
            stud1.name = "SpongeBop SquarePants";
            stud1.id = ("Student 1");
            stud1.mathgrade = 72;
            stud1.enggrade = 80;
            stud1.scigrade = 90;
            stud1.average();

            StudentGrade stud2 = new StudentGrade ();
            stud2.name = "Patrick Star";
            stud2.id = ("Student 2 ");
            stud2.mathgrade = 72;
            stud2.enggrade = 85;
            stud2.scigrade = 91;
            stud2.average();

            StudentGrade stud3 = new StudentGrade ();
            stud3.name = "Squidward Tentacles";
            stud3.id = ("Student 3" );
            stud3.mathgrade = 90;
            stud3.enggrade = 85;
            stud3.scigrade = 95;
            stud2.average();

            StudentGrade stud4 = new StudentGrade ();
            stud4.name = "Eugene H. Krabs";
            stud4.id = ("Student 4");
            stud4.mathgrade = 95;
            stud4.enggrade = 85;
            stud4.scigrade = 95;
            stud4.average();

            StudentGrade stud5 = new StudentGrade ();
            stud5.name = "Sandy Cheeks";
            stud5.id = ("Student 5");
            stud5.mathgrade = 75;
            stud5.enggrade = 75;
            stud5.scigrade = 95;
            stud5.average();

            StudentGrade stud6 = new StudentGrade ();
            stud6.name = "Gary the Snail";
            stud6.id = ("Student 6");
            stud6.mathgrade = 75;
            stud6.enggrade = 74;
            stud6.scigrade = 95;
            stud6.average();

            StudentGrade stud7 = new StudentGrade ();
            stud7.name = "Sheldon J Plankton";
            stud7.id = ("Student 7 ");
            stud7.mathgrade = 79;
            stud7.enggrade = 76;
            stud7.scigrade = 75;
            stud7.average();

            StudentGrade stud8 = new StudentGrade ();
            stud8.name = "Larry The Lobster";
            stud8.id = ("Student 8");
            stud8.mathgrade = 79;
            stud8.enggrade = 76;
            stud8.scigrade = 75;
            stud8.average();

            StudentGrade stud9 = new StudentGrade ();
            stud9.name = "King Neptune";
            stud9.id = ("Student 9 ");
            stud9.mathgrade = 79;
            stud9.enggrade = 96;
            stud9.scigrade = 75;
            stud9.average();

            StudentGrade stud10 = new StudentGrade ();
            stud10.name = "Pearl Krabs";
            stud10.id = ("Student 10 ");
            stud10.mathgrade = 79;
            stud10.enggrade = 76;
            stud10.scigrade = 75;
            stud10.average();

            /*stud1.printInfo();
            System.out.println(" ");
            stud2.printInfo();
            System.out.println(" ");
            stud3.printInfo();
            System.out.println(" ");
            stud4.printInfo();
            System.out.println(" ");
            stud5.printInfo();
            System.out.println(" ");
            stud3.printInfo();
            System.out.println(" ");
            stud6.printInfo();
            System.out.println(" ");
            stud7.printInfo();
            System.out.println(" ");
            stud8.printInfo();
            System.out.println(" ");
            stud9.printInfo();
            System.out.println(" ");
             stud10.printInfo(); */
        }
        public static void printTheStudentDetails (StudentGrade info) {
    }
    }
```

`StudentGradeApp2` Class:

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class StudentGradeApp2 {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            StudentGrade studgrad [] = new StudentGrade [10];

            Scanner scanner = new Scanner (System.in);
            for(int i = 0; i <= studgrad.length; i++) {

                System.out.print("Enter Math Grade = ");
                studgrad[i].mathgrade = scanner.nextInt();

                System.out.print("Enter English Grade = ");
                studgrad[i].enggrade = scanner.nextInt();

                System.out.print("Enter Science Grade = ");
                studgrad[i].scigrade = scanner.nextInt();

        }
            for(StudentGrade info:studgrad)
                info.printInfo();
                scanner.close();
    }
    }
```

Comment: Its clearly says assignment. your for loop is wrong. Here you are placing all the values.

Comment: please help me what should i change?

Comment: for(int i = 0; i <= studgrad.length; i++) should be for(int i = 0; i < studgrad.length; i++) {

Comment: i tried this but it still gives the error

Comment: @ignarapacon Next time onward do not post entire code here. Just post the part of the code where you getting error or exception and stack trace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have below issues with posted code for `StudentGradeApp2` :

- You got `java.lang.NullPointerException` at `studgrad[i].mathgrade`. It is equivalent to invoking `null.mathgrade`.
- `mathgrade, enggrade, scigrade` in `StudentGrade` are double and you are using `scanner.nextInt()`
- `For loop condition` is incorrect

PFB corrected implementation:

```
package javaDay3;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class StudentGradeApp2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        StudentGrade studgrad[] = new StudentGrade[10];

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        for (int i = 0; i < studgrad.length; i++) {

            StudentGrade sg = new StudentGrade();

            System.out.print("Enter Math Grade = ");
            sg.mathgrade = Double.parseDouble(scanner.nextLine());

            System.out.print("Enter English Grade = ");
            sg.enggrade = Double.parseDouble(scanner.nextLine());

            System.out.print("Enter Science Grade = ");
            sg.scigrade = Double.parseDouble(scanner.nextLine());

            studgrad[i] = sg;
        }

        for (StudentGrade info : studgrad)
            info.printInfo();
        scanner.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Now i do not know what to put on this portion:
>
> public static void printTheStudentDetails (StudentGrade info) {

You need a list to add all the Student grades

```
List<> studentList = new ArrayList<StudentGrade>();
studentList.add(stud1);
studentList.add(stud2);
```

Everytime you create a new StudentGrade object add it to the list.

In your StudentGrade class [override](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10734106/how-to-override-tostring-properly-in-java) the `toString()` method

Now in your method printTheStudentDetails pass the student's list `studentList`

```
public static void printTheStudentDetails (List<StudentGrade> list) {    
   System.out.println(list);    
}
```

Comment: In StudentGradeApp class

Answer (score 0):

Debug the code around where you are getting your issue. You'll find that your object is null. Don't forget to add your data to a list so you can use them.