# Printing out list returns weird memory reference

Tags: list, sorting, printing

So I'm writing a simple program that sorts lists.  I wanted to test it before I actually went into implementing the comparators/sort and I'm having an issue at the main method when it comes to printing out the contents of the list.  Here is my tester:

```
    public class Lab6Exercise {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //creates list of students
    List<Student> studentList = new ArrayList<>();
    //randomizes GPA
    Random rand = new Random();
    int randID = rand.nextInt(10000) + 10000;
    int randInt = rand.nextInt(4);
    double randDec = rand.nextDouble();
    double randGrade = randInt + randDec;

    studentList.add(new Student(randID, "Chester", "Smith", randGrade));
    studentList.add(new Student(randID, "Sally", "Winters", randGrade));
    studentList.add(new Student(randID, "Tim", "Jackson", randGrade));
    studentList.add(new Student(randID, "Winston", "Pulitzer", randGrade));
    studentList.add(new Student(randID, "Jackie", "Harris", randGrade));
    studentList.add(new Student(randID, "Paul", "Newman", randGrade));
    studentList.add(new Student(randID, "Sally", "Ride", randGrade));
    studentList.add(new Student(randID, "John", "Smith", randGrade));
    studentList.add(new Student(randID, "Cassie", "Anderson", randGrade));
    studentList.add(new Student(randID, "Sam", "Bowman", randGrade));
    studentList.add(new Student(randID, "Wade", "Mathers", randGrade));
    studentList.add(new Student(randID, "Jackson", "Pink", randGrade));
    studentList.add(new Student(randID, "Bill", "Throwers", randGrade));
    studentList.add(new Student(randID, "Tupac", "Shakur", randGrade));
    studentList.add(new Student(randID, "Amy", "Allen", randGrade));
    studentList.add(new Student(randID, "Charlie", "Waffles", randGrade));
    studentList.add(new Student(randID, "Cindy", "Decker", randGrade));
    studentList.add(new Student(randID, "Douglas", "Harris", randGrade));
    studentList.add(new Student(randID, "Jimmy", "Duggers", randGrade));
    studentList.add(new Student(randID, "Vince", "Eisel", randGrade));


    System.out.println("STUDENT LIST BEFORE SORTING: \n");

    for (Student stud : studentList){
        System.out.println(stud);
    }
}
```

}

and my output looks like:

```
STUDENT LIST BEFORE SORTING: 

edu.csu.lab6.Student@677327b6
edu.csu.lab6.Student@14ae5a5
edu.csu.lab6.Student@7f31245a
edu.csu.lab6.Student@6d6f6e28
edu.csu.lab6.Student@135fbaa4
edu.csu.lab6.Student@45ee12a7
edu.csu.lab6.Student@330bedb4
edu.csu.lab6.Student@2503dbd3
edu.csu.lab6.Student@4b67cf4d
edu.csu.lab6.Student@7ea987ac
edu.csu.lab6.Student@12a3a380
edu.csu.lab6.Student@29453f44
edu.csu.lab6.Student@5cad8086
edu.csu.lab6.Student@6e0be858
edu.csu.lab6.Student@61bbe9ba
edu.csu.lab6.Student@610455d6
edu.csu.lab6.Student@511d50c0
edu.csu.lab6.Student@60e53b93
edu.csu.lab6.Student@5e2de80c
edu.csu.lab6.Student@1d44bcfa

Process finished with exit code 0
```

So I'm assuming its using the address of the entire package and referring to the specific memory address where the student information is stored....How exactly do I get around this?  I imagine it should be pretty simple, but all of the various nuances of syntax aren't my strong suit in Java quite yet.  As you can tell, I'm still relatively new at this.  Thanks in advance for any help you can offer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are telling it to print out a Student object, not a string. So the output is up to however that class implements the ToString() method (or inherits the default).

You can either print the individual properties and format however you like:

```
// You don't show the actual property names in your code so I made them up
for (Student stud : studentList) {
    System.out.printf("ID: %s, Name: %s %s, Grade: %s",
        stud.ID, stud.First, stud.Last, stud.Grade);
}
```

...or, you can override the ToString() method on your Student class to return a string formatted how you want: [How to override toString() properly in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10734106/how-to-override-tostring-properly-in-java)

Also, not sure if it matters, but regarding this line:

```
List<Student> studentList = new ArrayList<>();
```

Any reason not to just use this?

```
List<Student> studentList = new List<Student>;
```

...so that it's strongly typed. The previous version stores as ArrayList of Object instead of List of Student.

Comment: NICE!  Changing it from new ArrayList<> to new ArrayList<Student> fixed the whole thing.  I also like your first tip for formatting, but upon trying it the compiler is unable to resolve the Format method for whatever reason..  Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Actually, I was wrong about that.  I was doing some research after I asked this question and was putting together a toString in my Student class trying to see if that would fix it.  Right after I wrote that toString I looked back at this question and tried your advice thinking that was what fixed it.  Turns out it was the toString I wrote, haha.  I realized this when I deleted it thinking it was benign code and started getting memory pointers again.  I do appreciate you taking the time to try to help though, thanks again.

Comment: Glad the ToString() fixed it. I'd still keep the ArrayList<Student> though. Just good practice. Sorry, my brain was in .NET/C# mode when I wrote String.Format(). In Java it's a little different but same concept: http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/lang/string/java-string-format-example/ I'll update the question just for accuracy/posterity.