# How to output an object and its variables

Tags: java, eclipse, class, oop, variables

Hi I'm trying to create "a class called HotelReport which, when given a Hotel object will produce a short, textual report describing the name of the hotel, the number of rooms and, for each room, lists the number and size of the beds.", but I'm unsure how to add the rooms and number of beds and get the final report to output, any help?

**Hotel Class**

```
import java.util.*;

public class Hotel {

// Hotel Name
private String hotelname;

public void setName(String hotelname) {
    this.hotelname = hotelname;

}

public String getName() {
    return this.hotelname;
}

// Hotel Rooms
private List<String> hotelRooms = new ArrayList<String>();

public void sethotelRooms(List<String> hotelRooms) {
    this.hotelRooms = hotelRooms;

}

public List<String> gethotelRooms() {
    return hotelRooms;
  }
}
```

**Room Class**

```
import java.util.*;

public class Room {

private int roomNumber;

public Room(int roomNumber) {
    this.roomNumber = roomNumber;
}

private static List<Bed> beds = new ArrayList<Bed>();

public Room(List<Bed> beds) {
    setBeds(beds);
}

public void setBeds(List<Bed> beds) {
    this.beds = beds;
}

public List<Bed> getBeds() {
    return beds;
}

public String getFormat() {
    return String.format("Beds:\t%s\n", getBeds());
}
}
```

**Bed Class**

```
 import java.util.ArrayList;
 import java.util.*;

  public class Bed {
  // size of bed
  private int singleBed = 1;
  private int doubleBed = 2;

  // implement single bed
  public int getsingleBed() {
    return singleBed;
  }

  public void setsingleBed() {
    this.singleBed = singleBed;
   }

   // implement double bed
    public int getdoubleBed() {
    return doubleBed;
}

public void setdoubleBed() {
    this.doubleBed = doubleBed;
 }
 }
```

**HotelReport Class**

```
 public class HotelReport {

 public static void main(String[] args) {

    Hotel hotelRooms = new Hotel();
    hotelRooms.setName("Intercontinental");
    hotelRooms.addRoom(1,2,3)


    }
    }
```

Comment: `hotelRooms.addRoom(1,2,3)` Do you know what this function does?

Comment: Because I dont see any method `addRoom` with parameter `int, int, int` in class `Hotel`...

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: What you want to do is override the toString method: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10734106/how-to-override-tostring-properly-in-java It's similar to the `getFormat` method you have in your Room class. You could make a similar method for your HotelReport class.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Hotel class:

```
class Hotel {
    private String name;
    private List<Room> rooms = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addRoom(Room room) {
        rooms.add(room);
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public List<Room> getRooms() {
        return rooms;
    }

    public void setRooms(List<Room> rooms) {
        this.rooms = rooms;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Hotel{" +
                "name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", rooms=" + rooms +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Room class:

```
class Room {
    private int roomNum;
    private List<Bed> beds = new ArrayList<>();

    public Room(int roomNum) {
        this.roomNum = roomNum;
    }

    public void addBed(Bed bed) {
        beds.add(bed);
    }

    public int getRoomNum() {
        return roomNum;
    }

    public void setRoomNum(int roomNum) {
        this.roomNum = roomNum;
    }

    public List<Bed> getBeds() {
        return beds;
    }

    public void setBeds(List<Bed> beds) {
        this.beds = beds;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Room{" +
                "roomNum=" + roomNum +
                ", beds=" + beds +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Bed class

```
class Bed {

    private BedType bedType = BedType.SINGLE;

    public Bed() {
    }

    public Bed(BedType bedType) {
        this.bedType = bedType;
    }

    public BedType getBedType() {
        return bedType;
    }

    public void setBedType(BedType bedType) {
        this.bedType = bedType;
    }

    public enum BedType {
        SINGLE, DOUBLE
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Bed{" +
                "bedType=" + bedType +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Finally usage:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        // beds for room#1
        Bed bed1 = new Bed(Bed.BedType.SINGLE);
        Bed bed2 = new Bed(Bed.BedType.DOUBLE);
        // beds for room#2
        Bed bed3 = new Bed(Bed.BedType.SINGLE);
        Bed bed4 = new Bed(Bed.BedType.SINGLE);

        // Room #1
        Room room1 = new Room(1);
        room1.addBed(bed1);
        room1.addBed(bed2);

        // Room #1
        Room room2 = new Room(2);
        room2.addBed(bed3);
        room2.addBed(bed4);

        // Hotel
        Hotel hotel = new Hotel();
        hotel.setName("Intercontinental");
        hotel.addRoom(room1);
        hotel.addRoom(room2);

    }
```

Get data:

```
// get the data
        String hotelName = hotel.getName();
        System.out.println("hotelName = " + hotelName);
        List<Room> rooms = hotel.getRooms();
        for (Room room : rooms) {
            System.out.println("room = " + room);
            List<Bed> beds = room.getBeds();
            for (Bed bed : beds) {
                System.out.println("bed = " + bed);
            }
        }
```

Out put:

```
hotelName = Intercontinental
room = Room{roomNum=1, beds=[Bed{bedType=SINGLE}, Bed{bedType=DOUBLE}]}
bed = Bed{bedType=SINGLE}
bed = Bed{bedType=DOUBLE}
================================
room = Room{roomNum=2, beds=[Bed{bedType=SINGLE}, Bed{bedType=SINGLE}]}
bed = Bed{bedType=SINGLE}
bed = Bed{bedType=SINGLE}
================================
```

Comment: A bit of explanation would be better!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you'd better add an `addRoom()` function in Hotel class like this:

```
public void addBed(Room room){
    this.rooms.add(room);
}
```

Then, override the `toString` function for each class above.

```
@override
public String toString(){
    String report = "Hotel name:" + this.hotelName;
    return report;
}
```

Use an ArrayList to hold all the instance of Hotel in your main function, and you can use a loop to retrieve them.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is kind of weird in my opinion. The `Hotel` class has a field called `hotelRooms` which is of type `ArrayList<String>`. Shouldn't it be `ArrayList<Room>`? That just makes more sense.

And in your `Bed` class, I am really confused about what you are doing. I think a better implementation would be

```
public class Bed {
    private int bedSize;
    //getter and setter for bedSize omitted. I'm lazy
    public static final int SIZE_DOUBLE = 2;
    public static final int SIZE_SINGLE = 1;
}
```

You can now set the bed size to double bed like this

```
yourBed.setBedSize (Bed.SIZE_DOUBLE);
```

Now that your problems are fixed, let's see how we can turn these objects into `String`.

To turn an object into a string, you can write a method that returns a `String` , something like

```
public String description () {
    //blah blah blah
}
```

However, you better use the `toString` method in `Object` for this purpose. Read *Effective Java* for more info of why you should do this.

```
@Override
public String toString () {
    //blah blah blah
}
```

And you write a `toString` method for every class that is related to the hotel. Let's see how the `toString` methods in each class would look like: (I only show the body cos I'm lazy)

Bed:

```
if (bedSize == SIZE_DOUBLE)
    return "a double bed";
else
    return "a single bed";
```

Room:

```
return "Room " + Integer.toString (roomNumber);
```

Hotel:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder ();
builder.append ("A hotel called").append(hotelName).append(".");
builder.append ("It has ").append (hotelRooms.size()).append (" rooms.");
for (Room room : hotelRooms) {
    builder.append (room.toString()).append (" has ");
    for (Bed bed : room.beds) {
        builder.append (bed.toString()).append (" ");
    }
    builder.append (".");
}

return builder.toString();
```

Now you can display the hotel's description:

```
Hotel hotel = new Hotel ();
//do stuff with the hotel, such as setting some of its properties
System.out.println (hotel.toString());
```