# Displaying an Entire JList to a JTextArea

Tags: java, string, jlist, defaultlistmodel

I am currently working on a point-of-sale system that has a JList that displays everything the customer purchased. After ending the transaction, I want to display the contents of the entire list into a JTextArea. I use the following code:

```
String s = listModel.toString();
jTextArea.append(s);
```

The JTextArea displays an odd-looking set of codes rather than printing the contents of the list.

I have read other articles related to my problem, but all articles that I have read only provides answers for printing a *single item* from the list but not *all*. Thank you everyone!

Comment: for example DefaultListModel has .toString() method defined as follows: `public String More ...toString() {
       return delegate.toString();
 }` and the delegate is `Vector<E> delegate = new Vector<E>();` that means when called `listModel.toString()` in code you would get what `delegate.toString()` returns. Probably your listModel doesn't have a nice output printing toString method defined. Take a look at **overriding toString()** http://stackoverflow.com/a/10734148/1737819

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take the model and append each element to the `JTextArea`

```
for (int index = 0; index < listModel.getSize(); index++) {
    jTextArea.append(model.getElementAt(index).toString());
}
```

Comment: I tried this code, but the jTextArea outputs


    prod2                                             45.75                                                           javax.swing.JTextField[,989,84,90x......[plus a Very long string of text.]

Is there any way to remove that?

Comment: Why are there text fields in your JList?

Comment: Here the thing, you should be putting components in you JList, the JList has renders for customising the data, you should just be putting the data into the JList

Comment: What I did is like this: When a customer purchases something, it is displayed in the jList. And when he ends the transaction, all of the products he purchased (w/c is in the jList) will appear in a jTextField (w/c serves as the receipt). But as I mentioned in the first comment, `prod2 45.75`(the product purchased, w/c is previously in the jList) appears, yes, but along with it comes this *odd-looking code* (`javax.swing.JTextField[,989,84,90x......`). Is there any way to remove that codes?

Comment: Don't add `JTextField`'s to the `ListModel`

Answer (score 2):

You may try this one,

```
int[] selectedIx = listbox.getSelectedIndices();  
String s = "";
for (int i = 0; i < selectedIx.length; i++) 
{
      s += " " + listbox.getModel().getElementAt(selectedIx[i]);
}
ta.setText(s);
```