# IntelliJ Idea template for toString method using String.format instead of concatenation

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I want to create IntelliJ Idea template for `toString` method using `String.format` instead of concatenation, `StringBuffer`, etc.

For example I have following object:

```
public class Foo {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private List<String> values;
}
```

If I generate `toString` for all fields by default Idea will generate:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Foo{" +
            "id=" + id +
            ", name='" + name + '\'' +
            ", values=" + values +
            '}';
}
```

But I want to generate following:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return String.format("Foo(id=%d, name=%s, values=%s)", id, name, values);
}
```

Comment: You should be careful with this. Even though String.format is more readable, it has very poor performance compared to old fashioned concatenation with +.

Comment: A newer approach with Java 8 and later is use of [`StringJoiner`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/StringJoiner.html), as shown in [my Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54838010/642706) to a similar Question.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

For anybody still looking for this:

```
public java.lang.String toString() {
return String.format(
"$classname (##
#set ($i = 0)
#foreach ($member in $members)
#if ($i != 0)##
, ##
#end
$member.name=%s##
#set ($i = $i + 1)
#end
)",##
#set ($i = 0)
#foreach ($member in $members)
    #if ($i != 0)
    ,##
    #end
    #if ($member.primitiveArray || $member.objectArray)
    java.util.Arrays.toString(this.$member.name)##
    #else
    this.$member.name ##
    #end
    #set ($i = $i + 1)
#end
);
}
```

Adapted from [this template](https://gist.github.com/smilix/9441452fc00d4d9b5391d487ebe848d9).

EDIT

For those who wonder what is this stuff (I wonder how you ended up here tbh, since the question is very specific xD): this is an IntelliJ template for  generation of `toString` method.

Code generation helps you generate code constructs and recurring elements according to preset templates, instead of writing everything by hand.

Please read more [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/generating-code.html) and [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/generating-code.html#generate-tostring) for toString specifically.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you @Linuslabo!

Comment: @linuslabo what do we do with these templates exactly?

Comment: @anon58192932 You can generate a `toString` method in your class, which uses the `String.format` (just like requested by the question). Give a look at [Intellij docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/generating-tostring.html).

Comment: Where in IntelliJ does this template belong?

Comment: @Basil have a look at the link to the docs in the comment above.

Comment: Essential information, like how to use this should be explained in answers, not just a link and certainly not just a link in a comment.

Comment: For those wonder where to put this template (just like me and @KrishnaAcharya), and don't want bother reading linked docs word by word(yes, there isn't a snapshot...), IT IS  IN THE DIALOG WHERE YOU SELECT THE FIELDS OF toString(). You can choose from the "Template" pull down list or add your own by clicking the "Settings..." button.

Answer (score 0):

It will generate the toString in the Json format.
[image]

```
public java.lang.String toString() {
#if ( $members.size() > 0 )
#set ( $i = 0 )
return "{\"$classname\":{"
#foreach( $member in $members )
#if ( $i == 0 )
+ "##
#else
+ ", ##
#end
#if ( $member.array )
\"$member.name\":" + java.util.Arrays.toString($member.accessor)
#elseif ( $member.string || $member.primitive || $member.numeric || $member.boolean || $member.enum )
\"$member.name\":\"" + $member.accessor + "\""
#else
\"$member.name\":" + $member.accessor
#end
#set ( $i = $i + 1 )
#end
+ "}}";
#else
return "{$classname}";
#end
}
```