# How do I output this array of test grades?

Tags: java, arrays, java-print

I am creating an array to print test grades and their cutoff. However, every time my output is this:

```
Grade@9c7e21
Grade@6194f8
Grade@258f60
Grade@418c57
Grade@1937e44
Grade@193a307
Grade@1a6cfa1
Grade@5b7a7
Grade@950d76
Grade@dceda6
Grade@102f6c0
Grade@681b92
```

What should I change so the output is the test grades and cutoffs?

Here are my 2 classes:

```
public class Grade
{
  private String grades;
  private int cutoff;
  //-----------------------------------------------------------------
  // Stores the possible grades and their numeric lowest value.
  //-----------------------------------------------------------------
  public Grade (String average, int lowvalue)
  {
    grades = average;
    cutoff = lowvalue;
  }
  //-----------------------------------------------------------------
  // Returns the possible grades and their lowest numeric value.
  //-----------------------------------------------------------------
  public String getGrades (String grades, int cutoff)
  {
    return grades + "\t" + cutoff;
  }
}
```

Driver class:

```
public class GradeRange
{
//-----------------------------------------------------------------
// Stores the possible grades and their numeric lowest value,
// then prints them out.
//-----------------------------------------------------------------
  public static void main (String[] args)
  {
    Grade[] score = new Grade[12];
    score[0] = new Grade ("A", 95);
    score[1] = new Grade ("A-", 90);
    score[2] = new Grade ("B+", 87);
    score[3] = new Grade ("B", 83);
    score[4] = new Grade ("B-", 80);
    score[5] = new Grade ("C+", 77);
    score[6] = new Grade ("C", 73);
    score[7] = new Grade ("C-", 70);
    score[8] = new Grade ("D+", 67);
    score[9] = new Grade ("D", 63);
    score[10] = new Grade ("D-", 60);
    score[11] = new Grade ("F", 0);
    for (int index = 0; index < score.length; index++)
      System.out.println (score[index]);
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the desired output

Comment: `score[index]` will be an instance of a grade object. Try overriding the toString method on your Grade object: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10734106/how-to-override-tostring-properly-in-java

Comment: create a toString method that returns same thing as getGrades and call that on the array item

Comment: @Nkosi 
A 95
A- 90
B+ 87
B 83
B- 80
C+ 77
C 73
C- 70
D+ 67
D 63
D- 60
F 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `toString` method to the Grade class

```
public String toString() { 
   return grades + "\t" + cutoff;
}
```

and use it in the for loop

```
for (int index = 0; index < score.length; index++)
    System.out.println (score[index].toString());
```

Comment: It works. Thank you very much!