# Parser implementation using Jackson

Tags: java, json, twitter

So far I have a tweet.json file which inside is collections of tweet. I have constructed a tweet.class which is a collection of objects from the key-value in the tweet.

now i want to implement a parses using jackson which should run through line-by-line in tweet.json and each tweet (line) is parsed to POJO. So each line is a single POJO

How do I do this

This is what I have done

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
ParsedTweets tweets = mapper.readValue(new File("tweet.json"), tweet.class);
```

example of json file

```
 {"text": "MVA/Transport. Greater Hume (Hume Hwy, Holbrook, NSW 2644) at 7 Mar 2017 03:58 #NSWRFS #MVATransport", "user": {"id": "4721717942", "name": "NSW Fire Updates"}, "lang": "en", "coordinates": { "coordinates": [147.273696, -35.785469] , "type":"Point"}, "created_at": "Mon Mar 06 17:29:31 +0000 2017"}
{"text": "Yes! Everything happens for a reason. The rain doesn't want the Swedru people to go&amp; flood Westhills mall this evening", "user": {"id": "724288148", "name": "Pyper Pebbles"}, "lang": "en","created_at": "Mon Mar 06 17:19:49 +0000 2017"}
{"text": "5 Sure-Fire Ways That Can Help You Achieve Better Success In Life , "user": {"id": "41049329", "name": "StarCentral Magazine"}, "lang": "en","created_at": "Mon Mar 06 17:08:36 +0000 2017"}
```

tweet.class

```
public class Tweet {
private String text;
private String created_at;
private User user;
private Coordinates coordinates;

public Tweet(){

}

public String getText()
{
    return text;
}

public void setText(String text)
{
    this.text = text;
}

public String getCreated_at()
{
    return created_at;
}

public void setCreated_at(String created_at)
{
    this.created_at = created_at;
}

public User getUser()
{
    return user;
}

public void setUser(User user)
{
    this.user = user;
}

public Coordinates getCoordinates()
{
    return coordinates;
}

public void setCoordinates(Coordinates coordinates)
{
    this.coordinates = coordinates;
}

@Override
public String toString()
{
    return "ClassPojo [text = "+text+", created_at = "+created_at+", user = "+user+", coordinates = "+coordinates+"]";
}
```

}

***Update ReadWriteJson implementation***

```
public class ReadWriteJson {



 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        assert args != null & args.length > 0;
        List<Tweet> tweet = new ArrayList<>();
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("tweets.json"))) {
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
                tweet.add(mapper.readValue(line, Tweet.class));
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you add an example of `json` as well as structure of `Tweet` class

Comment: Sure, i just added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the file contains tweets in the below format:

```
[{
    "id": "1",
    "text" : "abc"
}, {
    "id": "2",
    "text" : "def"
}]
```

And `tweet` class has the following fields:

```
class tweet {
    private String id;
    private String text;
    //getters and setters
    public String toString(){
        return this.id + "," + this.name + "," + this.text + "," + this.coordinates + "," + this.created_at;
}
```

You can use Jackson's `TypeReference` to deserialize the list, e.g.:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
List<tweet> tweets = mapper.readValue(new File("tweet.json"), new TypeReference<List<tweet>>(){});
```

**Update**
As per the updated class and file structures, you need to read the file line by line (as it's not a valid `json`) and deserialize it into `Tweet` object, e.g.:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        List<Tweet> tweets = new ArrayList<>();
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        try(BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("tweet.json"))){
            String line;
            while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
                tweets.add(mapper.readValue(line, Tweet.class));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, sorry i thought it was posted but my internet was done. Can you check it again please. I just posted it

Comment: yes thats what i was intending to do. read the json file line by line...thanks for the insight. But its not working there is an error message "Error:(28, 6) java: reached end of file while parsing". can you check the updated version i posted

Comment: Error or exception? Could you post the stacktrace?

Comment: its an error i think. there is an error with the parsing. the error shows "Error:(28, 6) java: reached end of file while parsing" which is the last line of the code. in " } "

Comment: how do i use stacktrace?

Comment: You might be missing starting/ending braces around the class, try the updated example in the answer (by creating a class named `Test` and copy/pasting the code).

Comment: yes i forgot to put the last braces. There is still an error message saying ("exception in thread "main" com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "lang" (class Tweet), not marked as ignorable (4 known properties: "created_at", "user", "text", "coordinates"])) which is think is because the original json file have an object "lang" but i didnt put it in the tweet.class because i dont want to include that. so how do i tackle this?

Comment: Annotate `Tweet` class with `@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)`

Comment: yes that work. Oh and one last thing how do i print the pojo(s)? the printing is not necessary. but i just want to see whats going on

Comment: Override `toString()` ?

Comment: i tried "System.out.print( tweet.add(mapper.readValue(line, Tweet.class)));" but the result is just true, true, true,.... | and what do you mean to use toString?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10734106/how-to-override-tostring-properly-in-java

Comment: I added the to string method in the test.class can you check? because its still not working

Comment: Updated the answer again

Comment: yes but its still an error, because it says cannot fine symbol for example symbol:variable id because in that class file there is only the class Test

Comment: Sorry, you need to move it to `Tweet` class, I have updated the answer

Comment: Hey can you help me further with my project please?

Comment: Sure, what's the question?

Comment: its regarding topic matching. so i want to analyse each tweet. and what topic they belong in. but with further conditins and specification. I sent you a message btw on facebook (im assuming thats you). If you care to look at the file its in google drive.

Comment: I didn't get any message, you can however post a question here and ask for suggestions?

Comment: It would be under message request as im not friends with you on facebook. Can you check again? And ok i will try to ask for suggestions here

Comment: I only have a day left, would you be able to help me? If so, you can give me your email or gmail so I can share it with you on google drive

Comment: I have included you in google drive. Now I have just over 24 hours to finish it :( Your help is greatly appreciated