# jest + graphql integration tests displaying errors

Tags: javascript, typescript, graphql, jestjs

I am writing integration tests against my `db` and `graphql` server.
`jest` is my test runner and assertions library.

For each test, I validate that I don't have any errors:

```
const actual = await graphql(schema, query);
expect(actual.errors).toBeUndefined();
```

When my tests are failing (something goes wrong along the way),
the `actual.errors` is not `undefined` and I expect `jest` to display the errors,
but this is what I get:

```
Expected value to be undefined, instead received
  [[GraphQLError: Invalid value [object Object]]]
```

This error message is useless if I can't see what is the "invalid value".
How can I configure `jest` so that it will print the error object?

Answer (score 0):

That is nothing with `jest`.The `[object Object]` is return by `object.toString()`,it invoked by the printer of the error log.
If you want see detail of the `object`,you need **rewrite** the `toString` of the `object`
It is like the below code:

```
obj = {x:"x"};
alert(obj)
obj.toString = function(){return JSON.stringify(obj)};
alert(obj)
```

Comment: In order to do it, I need to override the language `Object`, which is a really bad idea...

Comment: Yes, override the native `Object` is a bad idea, but you can override the objects which you want to print,and override the `toString()` is a universal approach for log in java,reference :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10734106/how-to-override-tostring-properly-in-java.
I analogy it to javascript.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is `GraphQLError: Invalid value [object Object]` you're probably passing the string `[object Object]` when you mean to pass the object. Or your schema has a string where you think it has an object, or you're passing an object when you should be passing a string. With out your schema, query, or roots I'm just guessing.

The graphql object has a few properties that wont automatically log. They do help debugging a ton however. `error.path` and `error.stack` are my favorite. You can see the full list of them in the [error object source](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js/blob/master/src/error/GraphQLError.js#L20-L78).