# How to get an Array List of Rectangle objects to Display the area of each Rectangle while using the Comparator Interface

Tags: java, list, arraylist, collections, comparator

I have a Rectangle class that in part of the code finds the area of the rectangle class using:

```
public double calculateArea() {return this.width * this.height;}
```

I have to create a second class called RectangleComparator and implement the comparator interface to compare two Rectangle objects according to area.  The following code is what I have come up with for that:

```
import java.util.Comparator;

public class RectangleComparator implements Comparator<Rectangle> {

    public int compare(Rectangle r1, Rectangle r2) {

        double areaDifference = r1.calculateArea() - r2.calculateArea();
            if (areaDifference != 0) {return (int) areaDifference;}

            if (areaDifference < 0) {return -1;}
            else if (areaDifference == 0) {return 0;}
            else {return 1}
}
}
}
```

My final class I had to create was a RectangleSortTest class where the method creates a List containing five Rectangle objects, not in order by area.  The method should print the list, displaying each rectangle's area.  Then sort the list, and print the list again showing the list has been sorted by area.  The following is what I have come up with:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class RectangleSortTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Rectangle> list = new ArrayList<>();

        list.add(new Rectangle (12, 15));
        list.add(new Rectangle (5, 2));
        list.add(new Rectangle (19, 10));
        list.add(new Rectangle (9, 5));
        list.add(new Rectangle (6, 10));

        System.out.printf("Unsorted list elements:%n%s%n", list);

        Collections.sort(list, new RectangleComparator());

        System.out.printf("Sorted list elements: %n%s%n", list);
}
}
```

Everything seems to run correctly but when I run the program and displays the following results:

Unsorted list elements:
[Rectangle@7852e922, Rectangle@4e25154f, Rectangle@70dea4e, Rectangle@5c647e05, Rectangle@33909752]
Sorted list elements:
[Rectangle@4e25154f, Rectangle@5c647e05, Rectangle@33909752,Rectangle@7852e922, Rectangle@70dea4e]

If you look at it the objects seem to be sorting correctly but I cannot figure out why it will not display the area of each triangle instead of the results I got.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your implmentation of `toString` doesn't output the area - It's using the default implementation. You'll need to override it to generate a  usable String based on your Rectangle. (Note - I say "your" Rectangle as it's clear you're not using `java.awt.Rectangle`, which outputs the x,y,w,h properties in its `toString` implementation)

Side note - your `compare` implementation is overly complicated. Why not just `return (int) areaDifference`?

Comment: I agree with you about the compare implementation.  Thanks for the advice.  I'm still confused on where to override the toString method.  Previous programs I wrote for the Rectangle class, in my test class all I had to do was    System.out.println ("Area: " + r1.calculateArea()); but with this ArrayList it will not let me do that.

Comment: Literally just define a public method named `toString` on your Rectangle class, and make it return something useful. It's the method that Java will call to convert any object to a String, and by default it is implemented by `Object` class to print the object's address (as you're seeing).  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10734106/how-to-override-tostring-properly-in-java) for some further pointers.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Thanks for the advise.  At had to put an @Override and define the toString like you said. Was all I was missing. Thanks again for the help