# Java Print ArrayList Groups with Group Name

Tags: java, android, for-loop, arraylist

I am just a beginner and learning Java to my own!
I just have an arraylist of objects of Users:

```
class Users{
   public userName;
   public userNumber;
}
```

then I create a model as:

```
 ArrayList<Users> model=new ArrayList<Users>();
```

and added the model items as:

```
 model.add(new Users("abc","123"));
 model.add(new Users("def","888"));
 model.add(new Users("abc","246"));
 model.add(new Users("def","999"));
 model.add(new Users("abc","456"));
```

What I want to do is to print the model in this way that should show similar grouped data with group name as:

```
 for(int i=0;i:i<users.size;i++){
    System.out.printlin("users:::"+users.get(i).userNumber);
 }
```

But it should group and print group by name too that is:

```
 abc ->
       users:::123
       users:::246
       users:::456

 def ->
       users:::888
       users:::999
```

So I want to group the data and then print the data in grouped format with each group name also!

How can I do that, I am just learning Java to my own. Thanks in advance

Comment: you need to use `java.util.Map`, this datastructure holds key-value pair. Your key will be userName and value will be list of userNumber.  

Then you can have a loop which prints the entries from map.

You can also read about java8 stream api.

All the best :)

Comment: if you want print data only then you can use oveeride method toString in user class . link (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10734106/how-to-override-tostring-properly-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

A quick and easy way to do what you want is to use a `HashMap`. Hash maps are key-value collections, son in your case, you would create a `HashMap<String, List<String>>` which stores the `username` as key, and the `userNumber` as a list of values (since you have more than 1).

Then your code would change as follows:

1. Iterate over all the users that your have.
2. If the `username` exists in the hashmap, add the `usernumber` to it.
3. If the `username` does not exist, add it to the hashmap with the `usernumber` as the first element of its list.

Lastly, you would then iterate over the hashmap, printing the key and values which it has.

Answer (score 0):

Try Something like below using Java Streams.

```
//group by user name
Map<String, Set<String>> map =
            model.stream().collect(
                    Collectors.groupingBy(Users::getUserName,
                            Collectors.mapping(Users::getUserNumber, Collectors.toSet())
                    )
            );
System.out.println(map);
```

Make sure to have the getter methods *getUserName(), getUserNumber()* implemented in Users class. Here i have assumed that both *userName* and *userNumber* are string typed data.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class User {
private String userName;
public String getUserName() {
    return userName;
}

public User(String userName, String userNumber) {
    this.userName = userName;
    this.userNumber = userNumber;
}

public void setUserName(String userName) {
    this.userName = userName;
}

public String getUserNumber() {
    return userNumber;
}

public void setUserNumber(String userPassword) {
    this.userNumber = userPassword;
}

private String userNumber;
}
```

### MainClass

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
public class MainMethod {

private static HashMap<User, ArrayList<User>> maps;
private static ArrayList<User> user1list;
private static ArrayList<User> user2list;

public static void main(String...args) {
    maps = new HashMap<>();
    user1list = new ArrayList<>();
    user2list = new ArrayList<>();
    User user1 = new User("Ram", "1234");
    User user2 = new User("Alish", "5678");
    User user3 = new User("Ram", "91011");
    User user4 = new User("Alish", "121314");
    user1list.add(user1);
    user1list.add(user3);
    user2list.add(user2);
    user2list.add(user4);
    maps.put(user1, user1list );
    maps.put(user2, user2list);

   /// User one lists
    for ( User userone: maps.get(user1)) {
        System.out.println("userone Name:::"+userone.getUserName());
        System.out.println("User one Number:::"+userone.getUserNumber());
    }

    System.out.println();
     // USer tow list
    for (User usertwo: maps.get(user2)) {
        System.out.println("User two Name:::" +usertwo.getUserName());
        System.out.println("User two Number :::" +usertwo.getUserNumber());
    }
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

please try the code below -

```
public class Users {

public String userName;
public String userNumber;

public Users(String userName, String userNumber) {
    this.userName = userName;
    this.userNumber = userNumber;
}

public String getUserName() {
    return userName;
}

public void setUserName(String userName) {
    this.userName = userName;
}

public String getUserNumber() {
    return userNumber;
}

public void setUserNumber(String userNumber) {
    this.userNumber = userNumber;
}

public static void main(String ar[]) {

    ArrayList<Users> model = new ArrayList<Users>();
    model.add(new Users("abc", "123"));
    model.add(new Users("def", "888"));
    model.add(new Users("abc", "246"));
    model.add(new Users("def", "999"));
    model.add(new Users("abc", "456"));

    Map<String, Set<String>> map = model.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Users::getUserName,
            Collectors.mapping(Users::getUserNumber, Collectors.toSet())));
    for (Map.Entry<String, Set<String>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        Set set = entry.getValue();
        Iterator value = set.iterator();
        while (value.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " : " + value.next());
        }
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
Map<String, List<Users>> use = model.stream.collect(Collectors.groupinBy(Person::getUsername)) ;
```

You use this approach to print the data by group