# how to change toString() value

Tags: java

How do I make it so I'm able to change the jar1.toString() value and put it in the player.toString() value.

```java
my programs output:
"Jill[](1) [a#1](1) [b#2](2) [c#3](3) /7\(4)"
```

```java
desired output when using turn() method:
"Jill[a#1](1) [](1) [b#2](2) [c#3](3) /7\(4)"
```

I've already made it so that when a player inputs the string "P" for pickup, it deletes the value in the 1st jar `"[](1) [b#2](2) [c#3](3)"`, I did this by making stone null and doing an if statement under the jar class `java if stone == null` we return the empty brackets `[]` but it is yet to transfer it to the player.toString() jar `"Jill[](1)"`

i've tried implementing if statements for `Class Player` String toString() method,

```java
   public String toString()  {
        return name + "[" + "]" + "(" + position + ")";
    }
```

something along the lines of 
`return name + "[" + stone.toString() "]" + "(" + position + ")";`

```java
public class Ground
{
    public Jar jar1;
    private Jar jar2;
    private Jar jar3;
    private Player player;
    private Chest chest;
    private String move;

   public String toString(){
    return player.toString() + " " +
    jar1.toString() + " " + 
    jar2.toString() + " " +
    jar3.toString() + " " +
    "/" + chest.combination + "\\" + "(" + chest.getPosition() + ")";

   }

   public void turn(){
    System.out.print("Move (l/r/p/d): ");
    move = Global.keyboard.nextLine();

   if (move.equals("p") && player.getPosition() == jar1.getPosition()){
      jar1 = new Jar(1, null);
    }
```

```java
public class Jar
{

    private int position;
    private Stone stone;
    private Player pos;

    public String toString() {
        if (stone == null) {
            return "[]" + "(" + getPosition() + ")";
        }
        return "[" + stone.toString() + "]" + "(" + getPosition() + ")";
    }
```

```java
public class Player
{

    private String name;
    private int position;
    private static Jar jar;
    private Stone stone;
    private Ground ground;

    public String toString()  {
        return name + "[" + "]" + "(" + position + ")";
    }
```

```java
public class Stone
{

    private String name;
    private int weight;


    public Stone()
    {
        System.out.print("Enter stone name: ");
        name = Global.keyboard.nextLine();

        System.out.print("Enter stone weight: ");
        weight = Global.keyboard.nextInt();
        Global.keyboard.nextLine();
    }

public String toString()
    {
      return name + "#" + weight;
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to override toString() properly in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10734106/how-to-override-tostring-properly-in-java)

Comment: @Sepp1 Note that bidirectional relations between classes (in your case `Player` 
↔ `Ground`) [may cause problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_dependency) in the future.

Comment: I will look into it thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `Player.toString` to include the player's `stone`. Also add a `stone` setter if you don't already have one:

```
public class Player {
    private String name;
    private int position;
    private static Jar jar;
    private Stone stone;
    private Ground ground;

    public String toString()  {
        return name + "[" + stone + "]"  + "(" + position + ")";
    }

    public void setStone(Stone s) {
        stone = s;
    }
}
```

Add a `stone` getter to the `Jar` if you don't already have one:

```
public class Jar
{

    private int position;
    private Stone stone;
    private Player pos;

    public String toString() {
        if (stone == null) {
            return "[]" + "(" + getPosition() + ")";
        }
        return "[" + stone.toString() + "]" + "(" + getPosition() + ")";
    }

    public Stone getStone() {
        return stone;
    }
```

And when the player takes the turn, have them pick up the stone:

```
public void turn() {
    System.out.print("Move (l/r/p/d): ");
    move = Global.keyboard.nextLine();

    if (move.equals("p") && player.getPosition() == jar1.getPosition()) {

        player.setStone(jar1.getStone());
        jar1 = new Jar(1, null);
    }
}
```