# I can't read an answer from server

Tags: java, android

I'm using Retrofit library for Android.

I'm trying to connect server, sending post request and well everything, But when i'm trying to get responce.body, i get the following answer :

*2020-07-04 21:37:45.931 18419-18419/com.androidapplications.mymetroword D/otvet: com.androidapplications.mymetroword.Posts@22bd74*

My Pojo

```
public class Posts {
    @SerializedName("email")
    @Expose
    private String email;

    @SerializedName("password")
    @Expose
    private String password;
```

//getters and constructor
}

My Interface

```
public interface ApiServices {

    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("authuser")
    Call<Posts> createPost(
            @Field("email") String email,
            @Field("password") String password
    );
}
```

My MainActivity

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        EditText email_add;
        Button btn_sign_in;
        EditText password;
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
        public static final String BASE_URL = "https://shavkunov.tk/";
        ApiServices apiServices;
        public String stat_auth;
        TextView msg;
    
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_in);
            //some variables
}

        public void postRequest() {
            Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
    
            apiServices = retrofit.create(ApiServices.class);
    
            Call<Posts> call = apiServices.createPost("1naesis@gmail.com", "1");
    
            call.enqueue(new Callback<Posts>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<Posts> call, Response<Posts> response) {
                    if (response.isSuccessful())  {
                        switch (response.code()) {
                            case 200 :
                                Log.d("otvet", "" + response.body());
                                break;
                            case 201 :
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "упс", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
    
                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<Posts> call, Throwable t) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "error: "+ t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        }
    
        public void onClickSignIn(View view) { //текст-кнопка "
            postRequest();
        }
    }
```

Please, help me)

Comment: response.body().toString()?

Comment: i tried but i don't help(

Comment: I did not what is your problem? Can you explain to us what is your problem in detail?

Comment: I want to get an answer (body) from my server. I try to send 
Log.d("answer", response.body().toString()); but instead String answer i get like this
@37c9cc8.
I know, this is standard meaning of toString(), but how can i to override to this method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to override the ToString() method in this class using the IDE or by typing it your self as now you are accessing the object allocation id and not the object values.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10734148/13867485 look at this