# Need assistance with question on java generics

Tags: java, generics

My output is currently:

> Avengers@15db9742 Avengers@6d06d69c

I need to figure out how to display the names as well, using the generic print method. I've been trying things like: `GenericMethod_violette.<Avengers>print(avenger.getName())` and `GenericMethod_violette.<Avengers>print(avenger.trueIdentity())` but after *days* on this I seem to be stuck.

My output needs to be:

> Avengers@15db9742 Avengers@6d06d69c
> Tony Stark, Bruce Banner

My `GenericMethod_violette.java`:

```
import java.io.ObjectInputStream.GetField;

public class GenericMethod_violette {
  public static void main(String[] args ) {
    Avengers[] avenger = { new Avengers("Tony Stark"), new Avengers("Bruce Banner")};
    
    GenericMethod_violette.<Integer>print(integers);
    GenericMethod_violette.<String>print(strings);
    GenericMethod_violette.<Avengers>print(avenger);

    
  }

  public static <E> void print(E[] list) {
    for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++)
      System.out.print(list[i] + " ");
    System.out.println();
  }
    
}
```

My `Avengers.java`:

```
public class Avengers
{
   private String trueIdentity;

   public Avengers(String name)
   {
      trueIdentity = name;
    }    

   public String getName()
   {
       return trueIdentity;
   }

   public String sayTrueIdentity()
   {
       return "Hello, I'm " + trueIdentity + "!";
   }
}
```

Comment: The normal way to get something to print is to add a `toString()` method.  Check here: https://www.baeldung.com/java-tostring

Comment: What you want has nothing to do with Generics. You should override the `toString` in `Avengers` class and change your print statement to `list[i].toString()`. `toString` is a method of the `Object` class so you can freely call it without worrying about generic. I skipped a lot of details for brevity. I recommend you to take a look at Oracle's Java Tutorial for better understanding of concepts.

Comment: @KartikOhri is right, each time you call `System.out.print(list[i] + " ");`, you are calling `toString` of Object which will print something like ***ClassName@hashCode***. If you want to print your own string you have to override `toString` method.

Comment: If you want your desired output with the object addresses, wouldn't you just need to run a for loop again in your print statement and do `print(list[i].getName());`? You could also do `print(list[i] + " " + list[i].getName()` to get the corresponding object address, with the name that is at that object address.

Comment: Thank you all! I got it working with a second loop thanks to DrZoo. Everyone's answers where very helpful. Very excited to make my first post on Stackoverflow and very grateful for all the suggestions!!

Answer (score 1):

you can use write toString inside Avengers

```
      public class Avengers
        {
           private String trueIdentity;
        
           public Avengers(String name)
           {
              trueIdentity = name;
            }    
        
           public String getName()
           {
               return trueIdentity;
           }
        
           public String sayTrueIdentity()
           {
               return "Hello, I'm " + trueIdentity + "!";
           }
           // write any format you want to print
           @override
           public String toString()
           {
               return this.getName() + this.sayTrueIdentity();
           }
        }
```

then change your GenericMethod_violette.print method to use toString()

```
  public static <E> void print(E[] list) {
    for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++)
      System.out.print(list[i] + " ");
    System.out.println();
  }
```

**Reason for Avengers print format - Avengers@15db9742**

```
In java all objects have a toString() method, which is invoked when you try and print the object.

    System.out.println(myObject);  // invokes myObject.toString()

This method is defined in the Object class (the superclass of all Java objects). The Object.toString() method returns a fairly ugly looking string, composed of the name of the class, an @ symbol and the hashcode of the object in hexadecimal. The code for this looks like:

    // Code of Object.toString()
    public String toString() {
        return getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode());
    }  

So you need @overrride toString method.
```

Comment: `@Override`, not `@overrride`.

Answer (score 0):

Your print result of `Avengers@15db9742` would mean that it is an object that you printed. If you want to print something meaningful, you need to override the `toString()` method of said object. In this case, of your `Avengers` object.

```
public String toString(){
    return trueIdentity;
}
```

> Added notes from [@markspace](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2338547/markspace) of [java toString()](https://www.baeldung.com/java-tostring).

Answer (score 0):

The class `Avengers` doesn't override the `Object::toString` method which `System.out.println` implicitely uses in its implementation. I suggest you to read more at: [How to override toString() properly in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10734106/how-to-override-tostring-properly-in-java).

However, this solution requires all the possible objects passed into the method to override such method, which you **cannot guarantee**. I recommend you to pass a `Function<E, String>` that *exctracts* from the generic type the field(s) as `String` to be printed out:

```
public static <E> void print(E[] array, Function<E, String> extractor) {
    for (E e: array) {
        System.out.print(extractor.apply(e) + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

The usage is fairly simple (the generic type can be omitted as long as it is inferred):

```
// both following lines are basically identical
GenericMethod_violette.print(avenger, a -> a.getName());
GenericMethod_violette.print(avenger, Avenger::getName);
```

```
// if Avengers have more of the fields or they are to be customized, ex.:
GenericMethod_violette.print(avenger, a -> "Mr." + a.getName().toUpperCase());
```

**Disclaimer:** This solution requires Java 8. If you use Java 7 or lower, you are stick to override the `Object::toString` in all the expected classes:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return this.getName();
}
```