# How to print content of an object

Tags: java

I'm trying to fetch a list from MySQL on android but I'm getting

```
[com.trycatchsoft.app.Models.KatPojo@7553fa]
```

as output instead of list.

Here is my pojo file:

```
package com.trycatchsoft.app.Models;

public class KatPojo {

  private Boolean tf;
  private String veri;
  private String verid;

  public Boolean getTf() {
      return tf;
  }

  public void setTf(Boolean tf) {
      this.tf = tf;
  }

  public String getVeri() {
      return veri;
  }

  public void setVeri(String veri) {
      this.veri = veri;
  }

  public String getVerid() {
      return verid;
  }

  public void setVerid(String verid) {
      this.verid = verid;
  }
}
```

Comment: That's the default `toString()` representation of an object . How are you using the Object ? Override it if you want to print the contents . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10734106/how-to-override-tostring-properly-in-java

Comment: thanks a lot my friend. i added public String toString() {
        return veri;
    } to my pojo file and now i can see my array. thank you again

Comment: yes it answered my question. the first answer was very helpful

Answer (score 0):

By default, printing an `Object` results in a class name and hash code. One can change this result by overriding the `toString()` method inherited by all children of `Object`.

Comment: thanks. i added public String toString() { return veri;} to end of my pojo file and now it returns my array

Answer (score 0):

When you're working with the Object type, you need to override the `toString()` method and call this method if you want to get the string representation of this object.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use https://github.com/google/gson
If you are debugging I find it easy to just print the json instead of writing toString. You can pass your object or an array of objects.

```
Gson GSON = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
System.out.println(GSON.toJson(<PASS YOUR OBJECT REFERENCE HERE>));
```