# Jersey Jackson JSON and Eclipselink JPA - How to ignore JSON properties of owned entities dynamically without @JsonIgnore?

Tags: java, json, jpa, jackson, eclipselink

So I have a database and a library full of JPA entities and I'm generically reading them on a Jersey Rest Service. When I try to read an entity, it recursively reads bidirectional relationships. I know that @JsonIgnore fixes this issue, but the database is too large to manually go through each entity and add @JsonIgnore to each field of owner entities.

Customer:

```
@Entity
public class Customer implements DomainObject{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2543387766776209353L;

    @Id
    private long id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="customer",cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
    private Address address;

    ...Getters and Setters...

}
```

Address:

```
@Entity
public class Address implements DomainObject {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2543387766776209353L;

    @Id
    private long id;
    private String city;
    private String street;

    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Customer customer;

    ...Getters and Setters...
}
```

Basically I want to ignore sending customer in Address's Json without @JsonIgnore if that is possible. If not, is there another JSON building technique I can use to generate JSONs that follow the JPA notations of owners and mappedBy fields?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could consider creating different objects for your REST services responses as described in the [Data Transfer Object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Transfer_Object) pattern.

This would require you to write more code but would give you more control over your services' responses even allowing your to add aggregates if needed to avoid unnecessary round-trips from clients to toy service as described in the Wikipedia article.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051182/what-is-data-transfer-object) elaborates more on DTOs.