# Good practice? Dummy object

Tags: java

For a project I have to process a lot of information from a database and link it together. The information from the database is processed into Objects with attributes represented by information from the columns.
So far so good, but when I want to display this information to the user, I need to link the information from several objects together.
Now my question is, is it a good practice to make a new (dummy) Object with a few attributes from the other objects? A new Object that contains exactly the information I need at that moment? The information is difficult to fit into an ArrayList or Map, which was my first approach. The object can be discarded when no longer needed.
I try to make use of MVC Design Pattern, and I'm not really sure if this way of thinking fits MVC.

Answer (score 5):

Sure it is. It is a design pattern known as **Data Transfer Object**.
For more info, see this question : [What is Data Transfer Object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051182/what-is-data-transfer-object)

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
My 'normal' objects are very simple objects, the model just contains getters and setters. Are they DTO's as well? But ones with a one-one-relation with their database counterparts? Do I need to make a collection for the dummy objects as well, with a controller?

Answer (score 0):

Seems reasonable to me, C# MVC uses this often and references them as View Models in their tutorials. Here is some inforamtion about this idea of a view model https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93viewmodel

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Can you make a View Model that is not linked to one Domain Model, but to several? And do you need to make a controller for the View Model?

Answer (score 0):

What you are talking about can be implemented [Strategy Patterns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) or [State Patterns.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern)

These design patterns are suited to handle and manipulate objects on the fly.