# is it possible to have conditional @Transient field?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Let's say if I have an `Entity` named person with lots of information including SSN. When other user query this person, I want to show a 'lite' version of person `Entity`. I could've done so by annotating SSN with `@Transient`, but that means the person himself would not get this field too. Is it possible to reuse the same `Entity` but return two different json to client? I'm using spring boot.

Comment: that's what `data transfer objects` are for. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051182/what-is-data-transfer-object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all `@Transient` just means that the value, the SSN in your case, won't be persisted to the database.
As for your problem annotations are static and cannot be applied dynamically.
You have 2 Options:

1. Define a new View class for your user.
2. Look at [JacksonJsonViews](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonJsonViews)