# Storing fields from a non entity parent

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have a class which I don't want it to be stored on the database, basically it is used for receiving such info from a http request.

```
class Address {
    private String address;
    private String postCode;

    // + getters and setters

}
```

Bear in mind that this class is not an entity.
Now I'd like to create an entity by inheriting from it.

```
@Entity
class StorableAddress extends Address {
   // id and a few more fields.
}
```

When I save a StorableAddress it doesn't save any field from Address (address and postCode). Is there a solution for that or do I have to copy all the fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer - **you should copy values and not use inheritance.**

What you are describing is a [DTO pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051182/what-is-data-transfer-object).

In order to avoid boilerplate code when working with DTOs, you can use tools like [MapStruct](http://mapstruct.org/)