# Spring MVC create object request

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm writing service with spring MVC to add books to library. So I have a method `@PostMapping(...) public Book addBook(@RequestBody Book book) {...}`
but the thing is `Book` object contains lots of fieds, but I want only some of them to **allow** to be passed to `addBook` request. Lets say in a book there is a field `lastRequestedTime`, and I never want allow user to fill this parameter.

My idea is to create new class `AddBookRequest` with all required fields, so my method will look like this: `@PostMapping(...) public Book addBook(@RequestBody AddBookRequest book) {...}` but in this case I will need to make lots of `**Requst` classes almost for every request.

How much am I right? Are there any better approaches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea is right, what you're going to implement is [DTO pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051182/what-is-data-transfer-object).

The idea is to decouple your request bodies from your domain model (assuming the Book is a business entity). They refer to distinct application layers: controller and domain model respectively.

Such a distinction has many advantages:

- Changes to the request logic don't affect business entities (and vice-versa)
- Request objects don't contain extra fields (that's your case)
- Serialization logic is not mixed with the domain model definition (for example, you may want to put some Jackson annotations on the properties of your request object)

However, note that there's one significant disadvantage: **code duplication**.