# Remove Property from Returned object in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have a .net core 3.1 API that returns customer information.  In this return there is a password field.  How do I stop the password field from returning with the customer object?

```
// GET api/<CustomersController>/5
        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Customer>> Get(Guid id)
        {
            var customer = await _context.Customers.FindAsync(id);
            if (customer == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return customer;
        }
```

I tried using `JsonIgnore` but that won't let me POST seeing as my model has a required field for password.

```
[Required]
[JsonIgnore]
public string Password { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a [DTO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051182/what-is-data-transfer-object) which doesn't contain a field for the password, and then return the DTO instead:

```
public class CustomerDTO 
{
    // Customer's fields without the password
}
```

---

```
[HttpGet("{id}")]
public async Task<ActionResult<CustomerDTO>> Get(Guid id)
{
    var customer = await _context.Customers.FindAsync(id);
    if (customer == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }
    var customerToReturn = MapCustomerToCustomerDTO(customer); // manually do this, or use some auto mapper
    return customerToReturn;
}
```